# Link not working in dashboard of react-admin

Tags: hyperlink, react-admin

I'm trying to make a Link from dashboard to some of resource in my project. I used button with `component={Link}` option.

It changes my url, but page remains same

It occur error in JS console:
 does not support changing `store` on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0 for the migration instructions.

and my admin interface not in root

```js
<Button 
  component={Link} 
  to={{pathname: "/new_admin/#/issuing_history"}}
  type="button" color="success" size={"sm"}> 
</Button>
```

Comment: Are you using the component `Button` from React Admin or from Material UI?

Answer (score 3):

React Admin is using [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) to manage its routing.

Also, the `<Button>` component from React Admin doesn't have the same API than the Material UI one.

If you want a link that looks like a Button, you should import the button from Material UI and use the react-router API to trigger a route change.

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyButton = () => (
    <Button
        component={Link}
        to={{ pathname: "/issuing_history" }}
    />
);
```

Comment: I did it before. It changes url in my browser, but component didn't change, nothing happends.

Comment: Maybe another important option. I have react-admin in another React app, with own router. But all thing work perfectly, i have problem only with this.

Comment: Oh, this is very different, then. You should call your own router within the onClick prop, IMHO.